# how to avail bg color for every bar in highchart

Tags: css, html, highcharts

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'John',
      data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

You can see blue indication of the data..Now the ramining say for example in grapes the remaining (10-7=3) i want to indicate in green. It should look like the data is blue and the remaining unconsumed part as green. It should be like background color for the bar because i dont prefer to give another data in series .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sujitha123/xbe5aa82/ Pls try this and help me

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xbe5aa82/1/

Comment: but the legend and data label is a hindrance in such case

Comment: See updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/xbe5aa82/2/ I have connected series using `linkedTo` option and disabled tooltip for green series.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts bars don't have a background color, so I don't think that you can do this without creating another series (or modifying the Highcharts code).

You could dynamically create a 'remainder' series in just a couple of lines of code:

```
chartConfig.series.push({
    name: 'Remainder',
    index: 0,
    data: chartConfig.series[0].data.map(function(value) { return maxFruit - value })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s261qdfr/